# Mapping JAXBelement in Mule Data mapper

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a generated SOAP response from a wsdl for one Web Service. This is how one of the elements looks like in the wsld definition:

`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>`

In the POJO, it looks like this :

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Name", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Web.WebServices", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
protected JAXBElement<String> name;
```

When trying to set the value, in the Data Mapper, I see the following:

[image]

The problem is that I am not allowed to just drag and drop the "name" value.
How should I map the name value from the JSON on the left to the name value?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drag  input.name to the value field of name name/value.

Script view should look something like:

output.value = input.name;

Comment: This does not work because the name in the POJO on the right is not a simple String. It is protected JAXBElement<String> name;

Comment: Do not drag it to name. Drag it directly to 'value' which is a string. Datamapper take care of the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didnt explain well, but what you just said is exactly what I did first place and it does not work because the "name" in the POJO is JAXBElement and not a String. This is the exception I am getting: Caused by: org.jetel.exception.JetelException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement can not be instantiated.